# How to track dynamically created subdirectories using google analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Is there any way to track dynamically created subdirectories using google analytics. Actually, I have a domain called www.abc.com. now on signup, a new subdirectory created Like

```
www.abc.com/store1
www.abc.com/store2
www.abc.com/store3
www.abc.com/store4
.
.
.
.
.
www.abc.com/store100
```

These all are created dynamically using the code on signup. Now i want to track all the folders created using google analytics code.

Comment: As long as the dynamically  created pages contain GA code GA will track them, dynamic or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ensure that you add your Google Analytics pageview code to all those dynamically generated pages. Google Analytics will start tracking all the pages.